# Firestore get all documents if child collection found

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to get all the documents if child collection have specific doc ID?

I created a child collection inside of a locations to store not public data:

```
admin.firestore().collection('locations').doc()
.collection('private_data').doc()
```

As an admin I wanted to collect all the locations with specific doc ID from 'private_data' collection. For example get all the locations docs if 'private_data' has doc uid equals to `k8AzwG...`

`admin.firestore().collection('locations').doc()
.collection('private_data').doc(k8AzwG...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore client-side SDKs don't offer the ability to make a query that yields collections.  You can only make a query that yields documents.  Whatever data you need from a query, you will have to find a way to model it so that a set of documents can be queried for the results of the query.